# Замена значений из одной таблицы другими Laravel[View]

Tags: php, laravel, table

```
TasksController:
```

```html
public function index() {
  $tasks = Task::all(); 
  return view('tasks.index', ['tasks' => $tasks] );
}
```

```
index.blade.php:
```

```html
@foreach($tasks as $task)
<tr>
  <td>{{ $task->id }}</td>
  <td>{{ $task->subject_id }}</td>
  <!-- subject_id нужно заменить на subject из другой таблицы -->
  <td>{{ $task->text }}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

**Такая структура таблиц:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### Как вместо `$task->subject_id` выводить `поле subject` с таблицы `subjects`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у Вас прописаны отношения этих моделей получить такой списом можно следующим образом:

```
$result = Task::with('subjects')->get();
```

Ну или же можете обойтись cтандартным JOIN